# Просуммировать элементы в List<T>

Tags: c#

Есть класс со свойством `Price`. И коллекция данного класса. Нужно найти сумму значений свойств `Price` у объектов в коллекции.

```
public class Class
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

List<Class> list = new List<Class>();
```

Comment: Вам нужно просуммировать прайс? Тогда при чем тут поиск?

Comment: Что такое "общее значение"? Нужно найти элементы коллекции, имеющие одинаковые значения `Price` / среднее значение всех элементов / сумму значений?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например так:

```
int sum = list.Sum(x => x.Price);
```

Только не забудьте перед этим добавить

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Хм.. Я забыл, что сюда можно делегата передать :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var sum = list.Select(p => p.Price).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int totalPrice=default(int);
foreach(var item in list)
     totalPrice += item.Price;
```